Colour not surfacing, it’s covered up 2D grease pencil
How do you draw a color on the surface of another color, but making sure that the other color is not covered up
But stating that it has two different blank grease pencil on the scene collection.
Like in the picture below
How do I make the black colour surface on top the brown colour.
the brown colour belongs to GP (HEAD)
The black clout belongs to GP (NOSE)
so how do I draw colours on the surface of these colours but stating that I use different grease pencil for each colours
I know it’s simple but I can’t crack my head round it

Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

You can slightly move one object along Y axis, as you would do in real life with real transparent sheets.
Either move the whole object in Object mode or move the strokes in Edit mode can work.
The amount of distance required depends on how far the clip start and end values are, both for Viewport Camera (for realtime monitoring) and Render Camera (what gets rendered).

